# Blackpill's adc read error when trying to read an NTC

Tags: embedded, temperature, adc, stm32f4

Devboard: *Blackpill WeAct v3.0*
MCU: *STM32F401CEU6*
IDE: *Platformio*
Core: *STM32duino*

I'm trying to rean an NTC using a simple voltage divider with a capacitor for filtering as shown in the circuit diagram:

[image: the circuit diagram]

The code flows as:
1- Set *temp_outpin* as **HIGH**
2- Read the adc value in *temp_inpin*
3- Process and save the adc value
4- Set *temp_outpin* as **LOW**

```
  digitalWrite(_outPin, HIGH);
  float accumulated = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
  {
    int adc = analogRead(_inPin);
    float rt = ((adc * rs) / ((pow(2, resolution)) - adc));
    rt = rt / r0;
    rt = log(rt);
    float temp = beta / (rt + beta / t0);
    temp = temp - 273.5;
    accumulated += temp;
  }
  digitalWrite(_outPin, LOW);
  temperature = accumulated / iterations+ offset;
```

The code works perfectly if I let the _outpin as **HIGH** forever. Just adding the line *"digitalWrite(_outPin, LOW);"* makes the reading erroneous. I tried putting delays (from 1 to 100 miliseconds) after setting as **HIGH** the pin and before and after setting it **LOW**.
I could let it **HIGH** continously, but that comes with an energy cost I prefer not to take.
Thanks for the help beforehand.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- Calculate the time constant of the circuit to get the delay you need to wait. A delay of 100ms should make the value more to the actual one, but I think you need more. The rise at the NTC is an e function. -- You might want to migrate this question over to [SE/EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) to reach more people with electronic skills.

Comment: "pow(2, resolution)" Calculating this in run-time using floating point arithmetic is ridiculous. Just define a compile-time constant - your ADC isn't going to change resolution on the fly.

Comment: (Hint: for an ADC with 10 bit resolution, the maximum value is `1u << (10-1)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was all solved with a delay. The error came from the charging time of the capacitor. In this case the *RC* constant is *100ms*, so I put a delay bigger than 100 after setting **HIGH** the pin, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The 100ms time constant is to charge to 63% of the voltage across the capacitor.  To charge to 99% will take 0.5 seconds.  What is it you are trying to "filter"?  It seems the correct solution is to use a more appropriate capacitor. Perhaps 10nF not 10uF was intended?  Either way it is not a software question.  You shouldn't be happy with this solution, clearly the hardware is wrong.

Comment: Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609386/rc-low-pass-filter-for-ntc (where you were already told to post your non-coding question) for example.  A 100nF cap will suppress noise above 10KHz by > 36dB.  Your filter is an order of magnitude too slow for the intended application.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. My hardware design was wrong. Thanks for all the clarifications.